# Trouble with a sentence 状況を変えてくれるのはいつだってあなたのその気持ちだってこと

Tags: translation

I came across a line in a manga and I'm not sure how I should translate it to sound good. This is the sentence:

> 状況を変えてくれるのはいつだってあなたのその気持ちだってこと

And here is my attempt to translate it:

> It's your feelings that can always change the circumstances (around you).

I really don't know if it sounds alright like this, something must be off. Also, isn't いつだって similar to いつも?
Or does it have another nuance?
Please, I hope someone can help me out with this in any way. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: For context, this sentence is said by a girl (older) to another girl who is younger, if that helps.

Comment: Honestly, your TL would be perfect if you moved the word 'always' up front.

Answer (score 2):

Without more context, I don't know what kind of 状況 they are talking about, and I have no idea what あなたのその気持ち ("that feelings of you") refers to. Please always include at least what その ("it/that") refers to when you try to describe the context :)

Anyway, since 状況 is used with 変えて**くれる**, probably she's talking about her own 状況. The literal translation would be:

> 状況を変えてくれるのはいつだってあなたのその気持ちだってこと
>   It's **always** your feelings that change the circumstances (around **me**).

In other words, "your" feelings are affecting the speaker in some favorable manner.

This should be correct only in say, 80% of the cases. Other translation will be possible depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think that I can understand the sentence a little better based on what the other users wrote. Hmm, for more context, like I mentioned previously, there are two girls. The younger one is in need of help, she did something that she regrets. Her actions led to an unfortunate event and she wants to try and fix things (that is the 状況 that she is talking about). She meets up with an older girl and asks her to lend her strength. The older girl, after hearing her story, says that line above to the younger girl.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is most of the way there. It sounds like there is a sympathetic tone from the speaker, and this くれる, though normally implies an act directed to the speaker, I think is being used in sympathy to the other person.

Here, いつだって is not **always** but rather **whenever**.

> 状況を変えてくれるのはいつだってあなたのその気持ちだってこと
>   It's how you feel that can make a change in your circumstances whenever.

Comment: Ah thank you! I also did a blunder because I seem to have omitted to type another word in the sentence. I fixed it now. And yes, the speaker (older girl) is being sympathetic towards the listener (younger girl), giving her an advice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Adding その where it is is just emphasizing that the feelings of the other person are the key there. Also, whenever as いつだって has the connotation of "in any given moment", which is why it might be translated as "always" sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

> Always it's your (good/cheerful/positive) emotion/character that helps to make things better.
>
> It's always your emotion/character that helps to make my (bad) circumstances better.